# Selenium chrome is not allowing extension to run

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I want to test Chrome extension using Selenium. Chrome extension is making the rest API call in the background. but Selenium chrome is blocking the remote connection.

**Error**

```
chrome_1   | Only local connections are allowed.
chrome_1   | Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
chrome_1   | [1553232680.777][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
chrome_1   | 05:31:25.002 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: OSS
```

**Code to load Extension**

```
var sw = require('selenium-webdriver');
const path = require('path');
const extensionPath = path.resolve( __dirname, './assets/SampleExtension' );

var chromeOptions = sw.Capabilities.chrome();
chromeOptions.set("chromeOptions",  {"args": ['--load-extension='+extensionPath, "--whitelisted-ips", "disable-gpu", "disable-infobars", "no-sandbox", "allow-insecure-localhost"]});

let driver = new sw.Builder().forBrowser('chrome')
                    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
                    .usingServer('http://chrome:4444/wd/hub')
                    .build();
driver.get('https://samplewebsite.com/').then(() => {
    console.log('web page open ')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
var os = require('os');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var path = require('path');

    function getLocalBrowser() {
    var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome'),
    exeName = {
        "Linux": "bin/linux/chromedriver",
        "Darwin": "bin/mac/chromedriver",
        "Windows_NT": "bin/windows/chromedriver.exe"
    },
    exeLocation = path.resolve(__dirname, path.relative(__dirname, 
    exeName[os.type()])),
    service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(exeLocation).build(),
    driver = new chrome.Driver(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome(), service),
    driverWindow = driver.manage().window();

    driverWindow.maximize();

    return driver;
 }

module.exports = {
    getLocalBrowser: getLocalBrowser
}
```

Comment: getting The specified executable path does not exist: ${exe} error.